# Wildcard to select all results in a where statement?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a parameterized query with various criteria specified for the WHERE clause, set by macro variables:

```
%LET criteria1 = 'XXXX';
%LET criteria2 = 'YYYY';
```

Is there a wildcard I can use to essentially remove the criteria for the second variable?

```
PROC SQL;
   SELECT *
   FROM Table
   WHERE
      Field1 IN (&criteria1.)
        AND Field2 IN (&criteria2.)
;QUIT;
```

I do not want users to change the query themselves at all, but have an option when paramterizing to bypass the second filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add some code generation logic. First decide on a special value to use, such as ALL, or just test if the parameter is empty. Then you can use macro code to conditionally add the clauses to the WHERE.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT *
   FROM Table
   WHERE 1=1
%if (%length(&criteria1) and "&criteria1" ne "ALL") %then %do;
     AND Field1 IN (&criteria1.)
%end;
%if (%length(&criteria2) and "&criteria2" ne "ALL") %then %do;
     AND Field2 IN (&criteria2.)
%end;
;
QUIT;
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be wildcard compatible with proc sql, but it sounds like this may be the best solution. Could you verify whether I need to put my PROC SQL statement inside of a macro to make this work?

Comment: Depends on how old your SAS version is.  Open code supports simple %IF/%THEN/%DO blocks like this example now.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to reformulate your approach and parameterize the entire predicate, as well as introduce a mechanism for default values. I will draft my proposal in Pseudo-code.

Given:

```
%LET criteria1 = 'XXXX';
%LET criteria2 = 'YYYY';
```

Your query would then be similar to (note the pseudo syntax: **is_defined(...) ? {predicate} else {pass_through}**):

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table
    WHERE
        is_defined(&criteria1) ? Field1 IN (&criteria1) else 1=1
            AND is_defined(&criteria2) ? Field2 IN (&criteria2) else 1=1
```

If either criteria is left out, then all rows filter through for the corresponding predicate.

Comment: What the heck is value-if-set?  Doesn't seem to have anything to do with PROC SQL code.

Comment: The goal was to suggest a generalised different approach that handles the entire predicate. You are right, this is not valid PROC SQL - hence the emphasis "Pseudo code".

Comment: I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide connected to what I believe is a Linux-encoded database. I follow your suggestion re: defining the entire predicate - I've adopted a similar approach before - but could you explain the 'or else' bit? I don't understand ```?: 1```

Comment: @bhbennett3, I have revised my answer for clarity. I am not familiar PROC SQL, but would like to believe there are directives to assemble the query dynamically. The "else 1" bit simply allows all rows to filter through for the predicate if the corresponding criteria has not been set altogether. For some DB engines, the "pass through" value is 'True'.